# When creating chrome extension which modifies css of page on domain, it is not working, how can I fix?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The following is my code:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(abcdefg);
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab, n) {
    if (info.status == 'complete') abcdefg(tab);
});

function abcdefg(tab) {
    var tabUrl = tab.url;
    if(n.url.indexOf("http://domain.com")>0&&n.url.indexOf("/page")<0) {
        chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tabId, {code: "body{display:none!important;}"});
    }
}
```

I did body display:none so that I could easily see if it was working or not. Well it is not working. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: You should try checking your background script for syntax errors. Also, what is `n`?

Comment: I added n but still doesn't work though

Comment: You are still checking the `url` of `n` instead of the tab, or did you just not edit that part?

Comment: should I write instead, `tab.url.indexOf("http://domain.com")>0`? I tried that and it didn't work either.

Comment: Can you offer a more precise example? Perhaps try for an answer?

Answer (score 0):

To start off, you don't really need a listener for `onCreated` because `onUpdated` is fired in all cases anyway and it is possible that `tab.url` may be undefined in the `onCreated` callback leading to errors. So let's just trim it down to `onUpdated`. Something like this:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
  if(tab.url && tab.url.indexOf('http://www.domain.com') > -1){
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tabId, {code: "body{display:none!important;}"});
  }
});
```

While writing this out I realized that your problem was checking if the index was greater than `0`. If you are checking for the existence of a substring that starts at the beginning of the string, the index will always be 0, so either check if it is `>= 0` or `> -1`, as -1 is what is returned when a string is not found.

Comment: What I want is a single specific url that is not the root of the domain.

Comment: Nonetheless I even tried just the domain root like in your example, but nothing happens to the target domain. I even tried html instead of body, but nothing happens. the domain is not affected.

Comment: @user2352308 The whole point of an example is that you can edit it to your needs, in this case change what url you are looking for. Did you not add `host permissions` for whatever host you are trying to do this on. Are there any errors in the background page?

Comment: yes lol of course I added my correct url ;) and yes my permissions are fine (tabs and all websites) as I have other scripts running successfully on the same domain.

Comment: @user2352308 I guess the next thing to do would be trying to insert css manually though the background page's console and seeing if that works. Then try throwing a `console.log` into the `onUpdated` method to see if it is firing when you want.